# Verifying that a k6 transaction used HTTP/2

Tags: javascript, load-testing, k6

When making a k6 HTTP request, how can I verify if the transaction happened using HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2?

This code does not work:

```
let res = http.get("http://some.url/");
check(res, { "HTTP/2": (r) => r.headers.match(/HTTP\/2/)}); //fail
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Proto` field in the `http.Response` object that you can check, which tells you what protocol was used. k6 will negotiate protocol with the server, and use HTTP/2 if it is supported.

This code should work:

```
let res = http.get("http://some.url");
check(res, { "HTTP/2": (r) => r.Proto == "h2" });
```

See also:

- https://docs.k6.io/docs/http2
- https://docs.k6.io/docs/response-k6http